# bootstrap 3 tabs in modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add tabs into my modal-body. This is the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="detailsmodal" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="details">Wipe følgende enheter</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="detailsmodalBody">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

After adding the ul i can't see the modal. When launching it the background fades black but i can't see the modal.

Any ideas?

Comment: works for me: http://www.bootply.com/IGD7TisHYW

Comment: ps: your last `div` is not closed.. but i guess this was just copy & paste..